# R function bdc_country_from_coordinates not working

Tags: r, coordinates, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to make a column of country names from a dataset that has one column for latitude and one column for longitude. However, when I use the function `bdc_country_from_coordinates()`, I'm receiving this error message:

> Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  :
> Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 1028 has duplicate vertex with edge 1033

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Attached below is my code:

```
library(bdc)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(rnaturalearth)

# latlong_data is my dataset with a column for lat and a column for long 
# called "decimalLatitude" and "decimalLongitude"

bdc_country_from_coordinates(latlong_data,
                             lat = "decimalLatitude", 
                             lon = "decimalLongitude", 
                             country = "country”)
```

I also ran the example on on [this page](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/bdc/html/bdc_country_from_coordinates.html) and received the same error message.